# Behringer X32 digital feedback loop

Tags: feedback, mixer, digital, behringer

I've been using the "new" Behringer X32.

Occasionally, and still without knowing exactly why, I get a digital feedback and the master volume goes to top. No specific frequency, just a digital feedback.
Some of the times without me touching anything.

I have a hint it's related to the effect BUS since the X32 has both effect in & out faders. Anyone has had this problem and has a solution/explanation to it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is often caused by accidentally sending a FX Return channel back into the Bus that is feeding the same FX processor that return is coming from, creating a loop. Select your FX Return channels and view the HOME screen, which shows you all of the 16 Bus sends for that channel on the right. Make sure that for each FX return, there is no send level to its corresponding bus. For example if FX Slot 1 is being fed by Bus 13, which it is by default, make sure that FX Return 1 is not sending any signal to Bus 13. Check this for all 4 stereo FX returns. 
Hope it helps!

Comment: Happy that you guys are paying attention and answer this here. +1 to that :) I had contacted Behringer about this before and the answer was not "so clear". Thank you John! Now I understand the problem better and how to avoid it.

Comment: John, by the way, keep an eye on the Behringer tag here. You will find others looking for help and you get a chance to "show that you care". http://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/behringer